# How to set custom Nvidia Powermizer?

Tags: 16.04, drivers, nvidia, graphics, xorg

My systems was Ubuntu-mate 16.04 with Nvidia Quadro fx3700m, driver 340.102.
I have to use underclock method with Powermizer for fixing the overclock crash issue (only this card).
I add a modify in xorg.conf, medium level:

```
Option
        "RegistryDwords" "PowerMizerEnable=0x1; PowerMizerDefaultAC=0x2; PowerMizerLevelAC=0x2; PowerMizerLevel=0x2; PerfLevelSrc=0x2222;"
```

Everything work good. Graphics clock was down to the safe zone. But then, I realized this clock was too low to handle graphics (gaming and render). There are 4 levels in PowerMizer (0 to 4). The medium level which I was set in xorg.conf, it's Level 1 here, but I really want it to be set at level 2.
So, what to do to PowermizerDefaultAC is level 2?

[image]